# Вывести изображения из XML

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, xml

Есть XML файл https://d3aqoihi2n8ty8.cloudfront.net/ . В нём записаны изображения. Как вывести их на страницу сайта?

Comment: "В нём записаны изображения." - Вы программист или где?

Comment: я полный ноль в XML

Comment: может, почитать про XML?

Comment: Я нашёл там ссылки и подумал что там записаны изображения :D

Comment: https://d3aqoihi2n8ty8.cloudfront.net/actions/4head/dark/animated/1/1.5.gif

Comment: Как вы получаете `xml`?

Comment: У меня есть файл

Comment: И почему вы решили сделать это на `js`? Может на `php`?

Comment: можно и на php. Главное чтоб работало :D

Comment: _нашёл там ссылки_ - вот, это у вас и спрашивают, в каком виде изображения. Можно ведь и в base64 сохранить картинки прямо в xml, и другие способы придумать.

Comment: `xpath` вам в руки